# How to use WebClient for communication between two REST API services with docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-webclient

I'm trying to communicate between two local api services using WebClient in a Docker environment. However, when I try to send a request, I get the following error:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException:
> finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused:
> localhost/127.0.0.1:8081; nested exception is
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException:
> finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused:
> localhost/127.0.0.1:8081] with root cause

I tried to run the program manually (without a Docker container) and it works. But when I try to run it in Docker, I get an error.

*I assume that the error lies in the wrong port settings in Docker.*

Part of my **docker-compose.yml** config

```
  backend:
    image: "backend-image"
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/backend
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
    networks:
      - platform-network

  mock-bank:
    image: "mock-bank-image"
    container_name: mock-bank
    build:
      context: ./mock-bank
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - mock-bank-db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://mock-bank-db:5432/mock-bank
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
    networks:
      - platform-network
```

My **ClientService.java** file in "backend" service

```
public Client getBankClient(long id) {
        Client client = webClientBuilder.build()
                .get()
                .uri("http://localhost:8081/api/clients/" + id)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Client.class)
                .block();
        return client
}
```

*My "backend" service uses port 8080 and "mock-bank" service uses port 8081.
I am accessing the "mock-bank" service*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with docker, you have to use the docker name instead of local host, if you want to call a service of an other docker:

```
.uri("http://mock-bank:8081/api/clients/" + id)
```

Because in case of docker, localhost is the docker where your client runs.

Comment: It would be good practice to get the name of the database container from an environment variable so that your code stays the same in all environments/deployments and you change the environment variable value in each deployment.